# Array operations in Shell

Tags: arrays, linux, shell

In Linux shell script, I define an array and a constant, and want to generate a new array by math calculation, like

```
ix=(100 200 300)
dh=2.5
y=$(dh*(ix-1))
```

But I cannot get the new array `y` because I have syntax error when I run the shell srcipt. How can I correct it to get the result?

Comment: Don't do this in shell script. Use the correct tool for the job, e.g. Python or Perl in this case.

Comment: Shells generally don't support decimal operations.

Comment: You have to use a  loop, the shell doesn't have any built-in mapping operations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a loop. And to perform arithmetic with decimal fractions, you need to use a tool like `bc`, most shells only support integer arithmetic.

```
ix=(100 200 300)
y=()
dh=2.5
for i in "${ix[@]}"
do
    y+=($(echo "$i * $dh" | bc))
done
echo "${y[@]}"
```

Output:

```
250.0 500.0 750.0
```